# Beaglebone Black OpenSSl crypto acceleration

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, hardware-acceleration, beaglebone

I'm running Debian Wheezy at my Beaglebone Black. Is OpenSSL using the hardware crypto accelerator by default? If no, how can I enable it?

Comment: What makes you think its not already enabled?  Here are some good [instructions](http://datko.net/2013/10/03/howto_crypto_beaglebone_black/)

Comment: Bad performance / big contrast of performance when my application is sending not encrypted requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably not, no. You can check with the following:

```
openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc
```

If each line shows around 3 seconds, it's not hw accelerated. You'll need to update your kernel, compile cryptodev and insert the module, then compile OpenSSL using cryptodev. Ready? Let's go!

First, update your kernel and install the headers (check the current version first!)

```
sudo aptitude install linux-image-3.18.5-bone1 
sudo aptitude install linux-headers-3.18.5-bone1
```

Now download and compile cryptodev (similarly, 1.7 may not be current when you're reading this)

```
wget http://download.gna.org/cryptodev-linux/cryptodev-linux-1.7.tar.gz
tar zxf cryptodev-linux-1.7.tar.gz 
cd cryptodev-linux-1.7/
make
sudo make install
```

Now you need to register and insert the cryptodev module

```
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe cryptodev
```

Now check it's loaded - this should output a list which includes cryptodev!

```
lsmod
```

To make cryptodev load permanently, edit /etc/modules and add a line containing only cryptodev at the end

```
sudo sh -c 'echo cryptodev>>/etc/modules'
```

Now it's time to download and compile OpenSSL (check your versions)!

```
cd ~
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
tar zxf openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2/
ls
./config -DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTDEV_DIGESTS
make
sudo make install
```

Check your version and speeds - you should see 0.10 - 0.15 second times

```
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl version
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc
```

Now what you probably want this for is OpenVPN, but a prepackaged OpenVPN won't be using this newly compiled OpenSSL, so time to compile it yourself again . .

```
cd ~
wget http://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-2.3.6.tar.xz
tar xvf openvpn-2.3.6.tar.xz 
cd openvpn-2.3.6/
./configure --prefix=/opt/openvpn OPENSSL_SSL_LIBS="-L/usr/local/ssl/lib/ -lssl" OPENSSL_SSL_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include/" OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBS="-L/usr/local/ssl/lib/ -lcrypto" OPENSSL_CRYPTO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include/"
make
sudo make install
```

You've now got a shiny new OpenVPN installation using hw accelerated OpenSSL!

```
/opt/openvpn/sbin/openvpn --version
```

Answer (score 2):

Download and build `cryptodev`.

Download debian `openssl` source package:

```
apt-get source openssl
```

Аdd build options -DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTDEV_DIGESTS by editing **CONFARGS** in the file **debian/rules**.

```
CONFARGS  = -DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTDEV_DIGESTS --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/lib/ssl --libdir=lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH) no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5 zlib  enable-tlsext no-ssl2
```

Build debian package

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Now you have your own openssl deb package with hardware acceleration. 
Just install and test it.

```
openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc
```

You have no need to compile openvpn.

Comment: Welcome to SU! Using "above" and "below" is not the best way of referring to other's answers since the presentation order is not fixed - better to refer with the poster of the answer.